# solving vector equations involving the L2 (or any other) vector norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

My question is very simple. How can we solve a vector equation involving the L2 norm, for example.

$$a + 2\frac{x}{\Vert x \Vert _2}=0$$

Even if a write it this way:

$$a + 2\frac{x}{\sqrt{\sum_i x_i^2}}=0$$

where $a$ is a real value vector with same dimension as $x$

I am not able to continue.

Thanks.

Comment: The first part of the sum is a number, $3$, and the second one will be a vector. To be able to add them up, the vector needs to be a $1$-vector.

Comment: Can you explain what $+$ is here? Since you're summing a unit vector and a scalar. Note that this has no solutions even if I assume that $3 = 3(1,....,1)$, since then every component of the unit vector needs to be $-3/2$.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, let's assume that 3 is a vector a with any possible value and same dimension as x. I will edit it

Answer (score 2):

$a$ has to be vector of length $2$, and hence we need $-\frac{a}2$ to be a unit vector.

We have $$\frac{x}{\|x\|_2}=-\frac{a}2$$

Any positive multiple of $-a$ is then a possible solution.

Comment: but, is there any way we can express everything in terms of x, such as:

$x=.....$

The thing is that in my real problem $a$ is a gradient operator and 2 is a lagrange multiplier, and $x$ is the variable w.r.t I want to get the optimum.

Comment: $x=-ka$ where $k>0$.

Comment: I think you could say $\|\mathbf{x}\| = -(1/2)\int \mathbf{a} \cdot d \mathbf{x}$, though I may be wrong

Comment: I do not agree because the normalization value K depends entirely on the value of x, and thus it cannot be part of the solution of x @SiongThyeGoh

Comment: $k$ is an arbitrary positive  constant. Remark: I m traveling with limited Internet access, slow response expected.

Comment: So, there is not a procedure to solve these problems? My problem is quite more complicate than this and I cannot let things depend on an arbitrary value. I thought there would be a procedure or  something like that

Comment: What else do u know about the problem? Currently the problem has multiple solutions. There is a restriction on $a$ for it to have a solution and any negative multiple of $a$ is a solution currently.

Comment: my problem involves optimization with restrictions, I put a post one year ago but no one answer it, that is why I tried to get this simple answer in order to continue https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612396/simple-optimization-with-inequality-restrictions